# How To Keep A Form Open after Validation Reload?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form that is shown (display:block) when a checkbox is selected. When the form is submitted the page reloads with the validation displaying.. I would like to have the form show automatically when the page reloads when it has the inputs with the class "error".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's difficult to keep this if you press F5. If you meant to reload the page programatically you can use AJAX to update only the blocks that you want to update. Or keep this information on a cookie or something similar (i.e. if the user is logged-in you may want to store this information on the server side and render the page according the stored user data)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways;

You could have your script which applies the validation errors add an attribute to the form when it reloads, and have your JavaScript / jQuery check for this attribute and set the form to show, or just have it apply the display:block style attribute in place of the display:none; attribute when it reloads.

```
style="display:<?php echo (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) ? "block" : "none"; ?>;"
```

You could avoid submitting an inadequate form in the first place, and use something like the jQuery validate plugin.

You'd have to post your actual code for a neater answer.